# C equivalent of matlab angle function

Tags: c, matlab, complex-numbers, gsl

I am dying here.  So I have a complex number(-4.9991 + 15.2631i).  In matlab if I do

```
angle(-4.9991 + 15.2631i) = 1.8873
```

I thought that angle basically calculated like

```
atan(15.2631/-4.9991) = -1.2543
```

Why are these different?  I need to write a c function that calculates the angle of a complex number.  I have done so like this:

```
#define angle(x) (atan((GSL_IMAG(x)/GSL_REAL(x))))
```

But that way gives me the -1.2543 answer, not the 1.8873 answer.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `man atan2` - it's more usefull than simply `atan`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-1.2543 + Pi(radians) = 1.8873 (with rounding)
```

As pointed out by others, use [`atan2()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/)

Comment: Oh damn.  Well that solved everything.                          #define angle(x) ((atan((GSL_IMAG(x)/GSL_REAL(x))))+ M_PI)

Comment: no... this would be true in only half of all possible cases. please take the advice above and use atan2.

Answer (score 3):

Although using `atan2` solves the problem, the actual question hasn't been answered:

> Why are these different?

You are missing that the tangent function is periodic, with period pi = 3.141592... So, when you write `z = atan(y/x)` you expect a number `z` such that `tan(z) = y/x`, but there are infinite such numbers, since `tan(z + pi) = tan(z)`. Of course, you get just one of these infinite values: The closest to zero, which isn't the one you always need.

In particular, note that since you are calculating the quotient Im/Re, you can't tell the difference from -Im/-Re, i.e. a minus sign on both componentes doesn't change the quotient, but it's the *opposite* complex number (same applies for 2-d vectors). That's what `atan2` and `angle` do: They check for the sign of each component separately, and then determine if +/- pi should be added to the result of `atan`.